# Why can't I write $P(X>5|X>1) = P(X>5)$?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I have a confusion with the memorylessness property of exponential distribution.

If exponential distribution is memoryless (i.e. the past has no bearing on its future behavior), why can't I write $P(X>5|X>1) = P(X>5)$? Why  $P(X>5|X>1) = P(X>4)$?

Can anyone kindly explain it to me?

Comment: This has to do with the [lack of memory (memoryless)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=memoryless+answers%3A1) property.

Comment: How would you answer your question if "1" were replaced by "6"?

Comment: @whuber, then $P(X>5|X>6) = P(X>6)$.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the case.  When you know $X\gt 6,$ that implies $X\gt 5,$ whence the conditional probability must be $1.$  But obviously the unconditional probability $\Pr(X\gt 6)$ cannot be $1.$  I hope this stark contrast helps you recognize the intuitive errors in your reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

This property emerges from the fact that the exponential distribution has a constant [hazard rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Hazard_function_and_cumulative_hazard_function).  If you look at the exponential random variable as representing a time-to-failure, this means that conditioning on past survival does not alter the distribution of the *remaining* time-to-failure.  The property can be verified from the fact that $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ leads to $\mathbb{P}(X>x) = \exp(-\lambda x)$.  Using this form for the survival function, for all $t \geqslant 0$ you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(X>x+t | X>x) 
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>x+t, X>x)}{\mathbb{P}(X>x)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>x+t)}{\mathbb{P}(X>x)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\exp(- \lambda(x+t))}{\exp(- \lambda x)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\exp(- \lambda x) \exp(- \lambda t)}{\exp(- \lambda x)} \\[6pt]
&= \exp(- \lambda t) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(X>t). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

In the case where $t<0$ we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(X>x+t | X>x) 
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>x+t,X>x)}{\mathbb{P}(X>x)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>x)}{\mathbb{P}(X>x)} = 1. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: It might seem like a quibble to point out your result is correct only for $t\ge 0,$ but because I offered an example in a comment with a negative value of $t,$ it would be nice to see a formula that was correct for negative values, too.

Comment: Well-spotted - edited.

Comment: Maybe you should add in $$=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X>x+t,X>x)}{\mathbb{P}(X>x)}$$ in your very first displayed equation so that the reader can see that you are starting from the standard definition of conditional probability but it is just  that $(X>x+t)$ is a subset of $(X>x)$ and so that $\mathbb{P}(X>x+t,X>x)$ in the numerator reduces to $\mathbb{P}(X>x+t)$.